# jQuery sum of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this working JS which checks if different checkboxes are or not checked and asigns a different price for each one that will later be summed up.

```
function priceCandy1() {
    var priceCandy1 = 0;
    var candy = document.getElementById("candy1");
    if(candy.checked==true)
    {
       priceCandy1=13;
    }
    return priceCandy1;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalPrice = priceCandy1() + priceCandy2() + priceCandy3();
    document.getElementById('totalid').innerHTML = "$" + totalPrice; 
}
```

Now I'm trying to code the equivalent in jQuery and this function does work:

```
$(function () {
    var priceCandy1 = 0;
    var candy = $('#candy1');
    $('#candy1').on('click',function () {
        if (candy.is(':checked')) {
            priceCandy1 = 13;
        } 
    });
    return priceCandy1;
});
```

But I can't grab the returned price into a function that will add up every priceCandy#. Out of scope but I don´t know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an issue of scope like you say, you could declare priceCandy1 outside the function, as a global variable.

```
var priceCandy1;
$(function () {
    priceCandy1 = 0;
    var candy = $('#candy1');
    $('#candy1').on('click',function () {
        if (candy.is(':checked')) {
            priceCandy1 = 13;
        } 
    });
});
```

Then use priceCandy1 in your totalPrice function and it should be able to fetch it.

Comment: I forgot to mention i was looking for an answer without declaring globals. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in the same function:

```
$(function () {
    var priceCandy1 = function() {
        if($('#candy1').is(':checked')) {
           return 13;
        }
        return 0;
    },
    calculateTotal = function()
    {
        var totalPrice = priceCandy1() + priceCandy2() + priceCandy3();
        $('#totalid').text('$' + totalPrice); 
    };

    calculateTotal();
});
```